# Edit existing TIFF file with LibTiff

Tags: c#, tiff, libtiff

Can someone share an example of how to edit an existing TIFF image using LibTiff in C#. For example, how can I add the current date on the top right corner to each page in a multi-page TIFF image?

Answer (score 0):

Neither libtiff nor LibTiff.Net are capable of doing that. These libraries are not general purpose imaging ones.

You might be better served by a general-purpose library like FreeImage.

And of course you could decode a TIFF image, process decoded raster and then encode the raster back. But it might be too much work.